Debugger Malfunction
I'm using Spyder through WSL2 (miniconda installed through Linux) and the debugger isn't recognizing breakpoints.
Upon starting a Spyder kernel in the Linux terminal with python -m spyder_kernels.console --matplotlib="inline" --ip=127.0.0.1 -f=~/remotemachine.json &, the following is printed to the console:
Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

After connecting to this kernel in Spyder's IPython Console and trying to debug a simple program, I find that the the debugger does not detect breakpoints.
If I instead start a Spyder kernel with
python -Xfrozen_modules=off -m spyder_kernels.console --matplotlib="inline" --ip=127.0.0.1 -f=~/remotemachine.json &

the issue with the debugger persists. Any suggestions on how to proceed?
